# How do I create multiple Image rotation sets on one page?

Tags: javascript

On the homepage I would like to show multiple rotating image sets. I found javascript that works perfectly to create one rotating set, but when I try and duplicate the script to create another rotating set with different images it will not work. What do I need to do inorder to make this script work so that I can include several different rotating images on one page. Any thoughts would be appreciated. I am not a programmer by trade I've taught myself the basics.

In the head tag I entered the following script:

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">

var howOften = 5; //number often in seconds to rotate
var current = 0; //start the counter at 0
var ns6 = document.getElementById&&!document.all; //detect netscape 6

// place your images, text, etc in the array elements here
var items = new Array();
items[0]="<a href='link.htm' ><img alt='image0 (9K)' 
src=' /Img/ContentArea1/AdOne/MainAd1.png'     
height='291' width='726' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image
items[1]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='image1 (9K)' 

src='/Img/ContentArea1/AdOne/MainAd2.png'      
height='291' width='726' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image

function rotater() {
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = items[current];
current = (current==items.length-1) ? 0 : current + 1;
setTimeout("rotater()",howOften*1000);
}

function rotater() {
if(document.layers) {
    document.placeholderlayer.document.write(items[current]);
    document.placeholderlayer.document.close();
}
if(ns6)document.getElementById("placeholderdiv").innerHTML=items[current]
    if(document.all)
        placeholderdiv.innerHTML=items[current];

current = (current==items.length-1) ? 0 : current + 1; //increment or reset
setTimeout("rotater()",howOften*1000);
}
window.onload=rotater;
//-->
</script>

<script language="JavaScript1.2">

var howOften = 5; //number often in seconds to rotate
var current = 0; //start the counter at 0
var ns6 = document.getElementById&&!document.all; //detect netscape 6

// place your images, text, etc in the array elements here
var items = new Array();
items[0]="<a href='link.htm' ><img alt='image0 (9K)' 
src=' /Img/ContentArea1/AdTwo/Ad2img.png'     
height='291' width='726' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image
items[1]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='image1 (9K)' 

src='/Img/ContentArea1/AdOne/Ad3img.png'      
height='291' width='726' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image

function rotater() {
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = items[current];
current = (current==items.length-1) ? 0 : current + 1;
setTimeout("rotater()",howOften*1000);
}

function rotater() {
if(document.layers) {
    document.placeholderlayer.document.write(items[current]);
    document.placeholderlayer.document.close();
}
if(ns6)document.getElementById("placeholderdiv2").innerHTML=items[current]
    if(document.all)
        placeholderdiv.innerHTML=items[current];

current = (current==items.length-1) ? 0 : current + 1; //increment or reset
setTimeout("rotater()",howOften*1000);
}
window.onload=rotater;
//-->
</script>
```

In the body I entered the following code:

```
<div id="placeholderdiv"></div>
<div id="placeholderdiv2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Owl Carousel: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html. It is a much more simple solution, with great documentation.

Add as many carousels on a page that you want. For each carousel on the page, create an instance of the slider like this:

```
var carouselCount = 0;
$(".owl-carousel").each(function () {

    $(this).attr("id", "owl-carousel" + carouselCount);
    $('#owl-carousel' + carouselCount).owlCarousel({
        items: 3,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 2],
        itemsTablet: [768, 1],
        itemsTabletSmall: false,
        itemsMobile: [479, 1],
        rewindNav: false,
        lazyLoad: true,
        navigation: true,
        navigationText: ["Prev", "Next"],
        // Responsive 
        responsive: true,
        responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
        responsiveBaseWidth: window,
        //Pagination
        pagination: false
    });
    carouselCount++;
});
```

Here is a live example: http://bit.ly/1mVGYCX